# Control row groups with pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

To read a parquet file into multiple partitions, it should be stored using row groups (see *[How to read a single large parquet file into multiple partitions using dask/dask-cudf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58437182/974555)*).  The pandas documentation [describes partitioning of columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/io.html#partitioning-parquet-files), the [pyarrow documentation describes how to write multiple row groups](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#finer-grained-reading-and-writing).  Using the pandas DataFrame `.to_parquet` method, can I interface the ability to write multiple row groups, or will it always write to a single partition?  If yes, how?

Although the dataset is small (currently only 3 GB), I want to [read into multiple partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58437182/974555) such that subsequent processing using dask will use multiple cores (I can repartition, but this creates additional overhead) (and I might work with datasets of some 10s of GB later, still small but too large for RAM).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply provide the keyword argument `row_group_size` when using pyarrow. Note that pyarrow is the default engine.

```
df.to_parquet("filename.parquet", row_group_size=500, engine="pyarrow")
```

Answer (score 2):

alternative answer for folks using fastparquet instead of pyarrow. fastparquet provides su functionality via [a differently named parameter `row_group_offsets`](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write)

```py
df.to_parquet("filename.parquet", row_group_offsets=500, engine='fastparquet')
```

From the documentation on `row_groups_offsets (int or list of int`:

> If int, row-groups will be approximately this many rows, rounded down to make row groups about the same size; If a list, the explicit index values to start new row groups; If None, set to 50_000_000. In case of partitioning the data, final row-groups size can be reduced significantly further by the partitioning, occuring as a subsequent step.