# How can I read each Parquet row group into a separate partition?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, parquet

I have a parquet file with 10 row groups:

```py
In [30]: print(pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile("/tmp/test2.parquet").num_row_groups)
10
```

But when I load it using Dask Dataframe, it is read into a single partition:

```py
In [31]: print(dask.dataframe.read_parquet("/tmp/test2.parquet").npartitions)
1
```

This appears to contradict [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58464198/974555), which states that *Dask Dataframe reads each Parquet row group into a separate partition.*

How can I read each Parquet row group into a separate partition with Dask Dataframe?  Or must the data be distributed over different files for this to work?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that fastparquet will read each row-group separately, and the fact that pyarrow apparently doesn't could be considered  bug or at least a feature enhancement that you could request on the dask issues tracker. I would tend to agree that a set of files containing one row-group each and a single file containing the same row-groups should result in the same partition structure.

Answer (score 3):

I can read using the batches with `pyarrow`.

```py
import pyarrow as pq
batch_size = 1
_file = pq.parquet.ParquetFile("file.parquet")
batches = _file.iter_batches(batch_size) #batches will be a generator

for batch in batches:
  process(batch)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `split_row_groups=True` with [dask.dataframe.read_parquet](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_parquet.html):

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet(file, split_row_groups=True)
```

Docs for split_row_groups:

> split_row_groups‘infer’, ‘adaptive’, bool, or int, default ‘infer’ If
> True, then each output dataframe partition will correspond to a single
> parquet-file row-group. If False, each partition will correspond to a
> complete file. If a positive integer value is given, each dataframe
> partition will correspond to that number of parquet row-groups (or
> fewer). If ‘adaptive’, the metadata of each file will be used to
> ensure that every partition satisfies blocksize. If ‘infer’ (the
> default), the uncompressed storage-size metadata in the first file
> will be used to automatically set split_row_groups to either
> ‘adaptive’ or False.